# What are the messages that pop up when the mouse is still called?

Tags: mouse, gui, terminology

When you hover the pointer over a button or element of a program and a window pops up giving information about it, what is the message that pops up called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tooltip](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Tooltip)